# Creating a Time Series plot

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following data formatted like this

```
Date  :       Value
1995Q3: 8,540.40
1995Q4: 9,573.90
1996Q1: 8,856.40
1996Q2: 8,841.30
.......
```

There are 80 observations
Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 stand for the 4 quarters of the year.

I am confused as how to create a time series graph in R with the data like this. I have explored the internet and haven't found anything that has been useful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've already tried, and what exactly it is that you don't understand?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything as i am new to R and dont understand it very well, and i havent found any information on the web that is similar to how mine is set up

Comment: Is the problem creating a plot, or changing your data so you can plot with it? (Your values are obviously factors in this example).

Comment: My problem is creating the plot

Comment: This is not a code-writing service, so show some of your work. My guess is that your value is a factor (as R doesn't have thousand-separator comma), which makes it hard to plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do it

```
# Your data        
        a<- rbind(c("1995Q3", 8540.40),c("1995Q4", 9573.90),
                          c("1996Q1", 8856.40), c("1996Q2", 8841.30))
                dates <- a[,1]
# convert dates to years with fraction
                year <- as.numeric(substring(dates,1,4)) + (as.numeric(substring(dates,6,6))-1)/4
                values <- as.numeric(a[,2])
#time series starting with the first value and quarterly data
                a<- ts(values,start = year[1], frequency = 4 )
                print(a)
                plot(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

data = data.frame(Date = c("1995Q3","1995Q4","1996Q1","1996Q2"), 
              Value = c(8540.40, 9573.90, 8856.40, 8841.30))

data$Date = gsub(pattern = "Q1", replacement = "/1/1", data$Date)
data$Date = gsub(pattern = "Q2", replacement = "/4/1", data$Date)
data$Date = gsub(pattern = "Q3", replacement = "/7/1", data$Date)
data$Date = gsub(pattern = "Q4", replacement = "/10/1", data$Date)


data$Date = strptime(data$Date , format = "%Y/%m/%d")

plot(x = 1:4, y = data$Date, type = "l")
```